# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function why this error?

Tags: wordpress, divi

I'm using this code to add carousel in divi theme  using shortcode but it kept showing this type error, can anyone help ....? thanks in advance

```
<script>> $(document).ready(function() {
$('.slider').addClass('owl-carousel');
$('.slider').owlCarousel({
   loop:true,
   margin:10,
   items:1,
   dots:true,
   nav:false,
   URLhashListener:true
 })
$('.slider2').addClass('owl-carousel');
 $('.slider2').owlCarousel({
   loop:true,
   margin:10,
   nav:true,
   items:1,
   dots:false,
   center: true,
   URLhashListener:true    
 })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Have you enqueued the Owl Carousel script and styling files?

Comment: yes I have added the cdn's in header footer snippets code

Comment: Okay, Can you check in page sour (  Ctrl + U ) if the Owl carousel is loaded on-site?

Comment: yes it's loaded

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be because of 2 reasons

1. As you're not using a `jQuery` object and just using `$` so can give you an error as in WordPress you need to use `jQuery` not the `$`
2. Your `owl.js` is not loading before you inline the script.

**How to solve:**

1. replace `$(document).ready(function()` with `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` or `jQuery(function($)`
2. If you're adding any external jquery cdn url then please remove it. WordPress comes with jQuery you don't need to re-add another jquery script.
3. Make sure your `owl.js` is loading on the header part(after jquery.js) not on the footer.